# VS Code suddenly adding quotes to compile path without known config changes

Tags: c++, linux, visual-studio-code, raspberry-pi, compilation

I'll try to keep this brief while still giving the relevant info:

I had a working system of projects running on a Raspberry Pi 5 that I had ported over to C++ from previous implementations in Obj-C, C#, and JS.  I got all the build settings working and have been progressing well, including the ability to perform test builds and gdb sessions, ever since.

Until this past weekend.  I did something which may have been stupid: I installed the RetroPie emulator on it to play some old games with my kid.  This is the only thing that I can think of that changed in between things working and them not working.

Now, whenever VS Code triggers the build / debug sequence through its terminal interface, it puts the input filepath argument in single quotes, like this:
`/home/[username]/Desktop/Synths/PhysicalSynth/*.cpp`
This appears to be causing `g++` to look for a file literally named `*.cpp` instead of the intended wildcard "all *.cpp files in the directory"

I cannot figure out how to get VS Code to stop putting the single quotes around the path.  It does not appear to be related to any syntax in the project's .json config files, I have looked over them and I do not think anything is wrong nor has anything changed there.

The actual error that is thrown is the fairly common "ccplus1: file not found" error.

I'm lost.  Any help would be much appreciated.

It works if I replace the wildcard with a literal filename that exists, but of course then in only compiles that one file and all the dependencies are broken.  It also appears to compile multiple files from the command line if I use the wildcard without the single quotes - but this creates further problems down the linking chain when I'm operating outside the VS Code managed interface.

Comment: "I had to add the space in the file path here in the StackOverflow interface to force it to display the asterisks" - No needs to space. Just wrap the whole path into **backticks**. That way the path will be displayed in monospace font and its symbols wont be interpreted in a special way: `/home/[username]/Desktop/Synths/PhysicalSynth/*.cpp`.

Comment: But where exactly you have specified that path with wildcards? Do you use that path in `CMakeLists.txt`?

Comment: It's in tasks.json, I don't have a CMakeLists.txt

Comment: Are you using CMAKE or not?  you tagged cmake but it sounds like you are using VS built in build system?

Comment: I'm doing it thru the VS build system, though in the background it is somehow going thru cmake as it doesn't function without cmake installed.  Apologies if that's a poor reason to use the tag.  But yes, I am using VS's build infrastructure as it's currently set up.